# How to change the name of a mutable array by a programmatically generated string

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am new in the forum and perhaps I asking a silly question, but I would like to know if I am running into a dead end.

I would like to change the name of a mutable array by a string which has been generated programmatically. Is this possible?

I have tried to get empty mutable arrays from an array in case the user needs some, but I think it is not very good solution.

I have not found any reference making some comments on it like .name, .label.text or similar which might help me.

The code is very simple

- rowNumber is a string which is generated programmatically
- zeroRow is a mutable array which transfers its values to new mutable array.

  NSString *newMutableArrayName = [@"row" stringByAppendingString:rowNumber];
   NSMutableArray *newMutableArray = zeroRow;

At this point I would like to change the name of the mutable array to the given by newMutableArrayName.

Am I asking for an unpossible thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want change name mean you can change all object into another NSMutableArray array
just like

```
NSmutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:@"arrayName"];
```

Comment: thank you for reminding me something so obvious. Thanks again